# how to display the number of filtered rows outside table definition?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have implemented a filter for my `ngtable`. Trying to display the number of filtered items like this:

How to display `nr` of filtered rows here? Outside the table definition?

`{{filtered.length}}` result(s) matching the filter

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
                    <tr ng-repeat="account in filtered =($data  | filter:search.accountName | filter:search.id)">
                      <td>{{filtered.length}}</td>
                      <td data-title="'id'">
                        {{account.account.accountId.id}}
                      </td>
                      <td data-title="'name'">
                        {{account.account.accountName}}
                      </td>

                    </tr>
</table>
```

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Sx4YAO?p=preview

Comment: Create one more table like that. One of them use filter, other one doen't use filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add $parent before your filtered in your ng-repeat and you should be fine.
Ng-repeat has an isolated scope.

`<tr ng-repeat="account in $parent.filtered =($data  | filter:search.accountName | filter:search.id)">`

Answer (score 0):

If you create the array before you use it within the child scopes then they'll reference and use the one from the parent scope

JS

```
$scope.model = {filtered:[]}
```

HTML

```
How to display nr of filtered? {{model.filtered.length}} result(s) matching the filter
<tr ng-repeat="account in model.filtered =($data  | filter:search.accountName | filter:search.id)">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/mcuN34?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

Use built in function:

```
total() {{ tableParams.total() }}
```

Comment: This should be a comment